# How to replace existing .jar file with new one?

Tags: java

I have an updater that will download a .jar file - if it is new, and then quitting the application and then replace the .jar file with the updated one and then the user will be able to execute that updated version?

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: By starting a Java IDE and programming it. Does this answer help you? No? Then please be a bit more specific about which one of the steps you described you need help with and what exactly you need to know.

Comment: http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.nl/2010/11/runtimeaddshutdownhook.html put your copy-command in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a problem with overwriting the file while it is currently in use? This heavily depends on the operating system: On Windows, Java locks all jar files which are currently in use, so overwriting is not possible. On Linux, overwriting possible, but because Java doesn't copy the whole file into RAM, it can happen that your code fails at some stage because it isn't possible anymore to load new classes from the file (this is likely to happen for example for a class AskShutdownDialog which will only by used at shutdown). I don't know about MacOS, but I think this approach is to weak to even try it.

There are many tricks to get around this problem:

- You can use a helper application: Start it using a `java -jar updatehelper.jar` call, then quit your main application. The UpdateHelper will wait for your application to quit, then replace the files (which you downloaded and verified before) and start the main application again using another java call.
- You can also use a command line script as helper, but at least on Windows it's not very easy to develop and you need operating system specific scripts

Both of these options require some operating system specific code, at least to find your java binary to start the main application again. This can lead to problems (not only) on untested OSes

- A completely different way is to implement a Loader. This is a small jar file which will not change for a long time. This Loader can discover your main jar, for example MyMain-1.01.jar (it's a good idea to load this information including the classpath from a config file). It then loads this file and calls the real main class in it (you will also need an own classloader for it). With this setup you don't need any os dependent code, but you need to know that your Loader will be always locked at least in Windows. But even then you still have the option to introduce an UpdateHelper in a newer version of your application.
  I used this option once and had a very stable update concept over years without the need to replace the loader. The loader displayed a splash screen with progress bar and downloaded the update directly from a web server. If you want something like this, you should also consider using [Java WebStart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) which basically does the same thing.
- There is also the option for hot deployment, which means you unload a jar file at runtime. But this requires a very modular application design and no hard references between modules. This is the domain of application servers and webservers like Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss etc which use individual classloaders, maybe spring can also do this today.